# Node js 'console' error in cmd

Tags: javascript, node.js, console.log

I want to use the node.js on the windows. so I install node but I can't execute a .js file. That is my source code. And I atteched the error screen.

helloworld.js

```
console.log("Hello, World!")
```

[image]

Comment: don't name your file node.js i think it confuses it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error is happening because your script is not executed with nodejs but with Microsoft jscript.

The command you wrote "node node.js" is executing the file `ode.js` instead of the nodejs in your system in the same way you can execute cmd by typing `cmd` instead of `cmd.exe`.

To fix that you need to do one of those :

- rename the file to something other than `node`
- move the file named `node` in a subfolder (i.e. `src/node.js`)
- associate `.js` file with `nodejs` instead of `microsoft jscript`